# How it is possible to show a choice field (checkboxes) with the selected value

Tags: symfony

I use an Symfony2 form with a choice field based on 4 checkboxes. Now i have the Problem, that i can't reload data in this choice field.That means, when in the database the value 9 is stored, will the checkbox "unknown if "lang test" performed" **not be selected**, when i load the entity in this form.

```
->add('fu5LangTest', 'choice', array(
           'choices' =>array(
               'poor compliance'=>0, 
               'negative'=>1, 
               'positive (recognizes at least 1 image reliably)'=>2,
               'unknown if "lang test" performed'=>9),
           'choice_value' =>function (DataEFu5 $entity = null) {
                            return $entity ? $entity->getFu5LangTest() : '';
                          },
           'expanded'=>true))
```

I tried a lot of things with the choice_value Attribut, but i think i'm using it wrong. Whats the right way? i didn't found some useful Information. What i have to do, that the correct checkbox will be selected after an reload?

The storing process is working fine.

Thanks for an feedback

Comment: You want the form not to be selected if the db value is 9?

Comment: No the form has to be selected!, but when i do it like in your post, it also does not work.  In my db i store in the Fu5LangTest field the value {0} or {1} or {2} or {9}. Does the choice field not automatic take this Integer value and select the right checkbox?  Fu5LangTest  is a simple datatype and not an array. Thanks

Comment: sorry my comment was not finish before..:)

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't get it was an array. So`$dataEFu5->getFu5LangTest();` give you a php array like `[2,9]`?

Comment: Hello thx for your answer:) No the function $dataEFu5->getFu5LangTest() result me an single value like 9 and not an array. But when i make the form like in your example it doesnt work. Although the value 9 is stored in the variable fu5LangTest.

Answer (score 0):

The form is not the right place to do domain Logic.
Anyway, the data has the current fu5LangTest value. You should use

```
->add('fu5LangTest', 'choice', array(
       'choices' =>array(
           'poor compliance'=>0, 
           'negative'=>1, 
           'positive (recognizes at least 1 image reliably)'=>2,
           'unknown if "lang test" performed'=>9
       ),
       // ...
```

Form creation in Controller:

```
$object = new DataEFu5(); //or get it by your repository
//this condition will be better in a service as it is business logic ;)
if(!in_array($object->getFu5LangTest, [0,1,2])) {
   $object->setFu5LangTest(9);
}

$form = $this->createForm(ObjectType, $object);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. usually i work with this kind of logic in the MVC Pattern, but it does not work, when i load an entity i this form, thtats the reason why i tried it directli with the function in the form:) i saw some examples.